# Get Ember-data model type from string

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I have a model type defined like this:

```
App.Model = DS.Model.extend({});
```

How could I construct the type from a string like 'model';

I dwant to be to be generic about using the store, instead of having to be specific like this:

```
App.store.load(App.model, obj);
```

Comment: It seems odd to me that you have to include the model type when the root is required in the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can solve your issue using `Ember.getPath`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/SGsU7/:

```js
App.Model = Ember.Object.extend();

var capitalize = function(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

var string = 'model';
var capitalizedString = capitalized(string); // Model

var type = Ember.getPath(App, capitalizedString);

console.log(type === App.Model); // true
```

​